# Is it possible to pacify the Minetown watch?

Tags: nethack

Recently, I was in Minetown and was attacked by some sort of monster that caused me to begin hallucinating. Without noticing this fact right away (I'm still adjusting to a new user interface), I accidentally attacked what turned out to be a watchman. I don't know whether or not I actually killed him, but I received no "you murderer!" messages. (I don't know whether hallucination affects that message's appearance or not, though).

In such a situation, is there anything one can do to get the guards to forgive you? What about angering the town watch through other means (vandalizing, theft, breaking and entering)  -- are those treated the same way as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but i found this in Nethackwiki: http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Watchman

> Pacifying all hostile shopkeepers by paying them off also pacifies any angry watchmen on  the level, so you can pacify all the watchpeople in mine town by stealing something inexpensive (a gold piece) from a shop and paying for it when the angry shopkeeper comes after you.

Usually when i get hallucinated in such places I try not to attack anything, unless it hits me first, because then it's no Watchman or Pet. Coming back later letting your Pet kill the Watchmen is also an option.
As far as I know, every kind of crime is treated the same way.

Comment: This worked for me in the 3.6.1 beta.

Answer (score -1):

a scroll of taming should be able to do it.